# Android Material and appcompat Manifest merger failed in react-native or ExpoKit

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I updated 'android.support:appcompat-v7' to `28.0.0`.

But it brought an error from the build.

```
Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91

    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).

    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-23:19 to override.
```

Then I get this error in my Logcat:

> Manifest merger failed

my app.gradle:

```
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"
  }
...
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

  // Our dependencies
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'


  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

how do I fix it?

I need your solutions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: having the same issue.... my app was working fine yesterday, but today i just run the command `react-native run-android` and rest is history.

Comment: @PatelDhara unfortunately no, i will definitely post some where if i have a solution

Comment: @PatelDhara this is great, how did you do that? can you please share the solution?

Comment: @MDHusnainTahir I have shared my solution as an answer. you can see below.  If that solution doesn't work for you then share your package.json file. I may help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution through my search by referring to @MehulSolanki answer.

I add

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

in my  on `AndroidManifest.xml`

and update com.android.tools.build:gradl:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
  }
```

And add this in your gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

> ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${animal.sniffer.version}'
>
> ERROR: [TAG] Failed to resolve variable '${junit.version}'

In case of above error

1. File -> Invalidate Caches / restart
2. Build -> Clean project

> error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
>   error: cannot find symbol class Nullable

In case of above error

Add `implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'`

change  `import android.support.annotation.Nullable;` => `androidx.annotation.Nullable;`

change  `import android.support.annotation.NonNull;` => `androidx.annotation.NonNull;`

> **Compile version** and **target version** should be **28.**

Comment: @HussainSherwani Could you update `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` ?

Comment: classpath is already updated which is `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'`

Comment: @HussainSherwani  Add this in your gradle.properties file `android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true`

Comment: thanks mate for helping but this will not work as due to these line those `libraries` not using `androidx package` will not compile like after adding these lines I am getting issue in `@react-native-community_netinfo` library which is using android package instead of `androidx`

Comment: @HussainSherwani  Did you add a library of real-native-commonity_netinfo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195105/discussion-between-hussain-sherwani-and-hong-develop).

Comment: @hongdevelop I have tried your solution. but there is a package android.support.annotation does not exist error: cannot find symbol class Nullable error from the react-native-fast-image library. and I'm not able to edit import in that library file. can you please suggest me how can I do that?

Comment: I have same issue. Did you resolve it @PatelDhara

Answer (score 48):

Upgrading `'react-native-device-info'` to `version 2.1.2` fixed the error for me. See [github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25294#issuecomment-503024749](http://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25294#issuecomment-503024749)

In short: the library used `"services-gcm:+"` as a dependency, and the latest gcm version caused this problem.

Answer (score 13):

The root cause is related migration to `Androidx`, google play service updated to androidX
Thanks to [MR03web](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25293#issuecomment-503008149) This problem belongs to react-native-device-info? best option is to upgrade `react-native-device-info` using

```
yarn upgrade react-native-device-info@2.1.2
cd android && gradlew clean
react-native run-android
```

or if you don't want to upgrade you should exclude `com.google.android.gms` from `react-native-device-info` like this. Thanks

```
implementation(project(":react-native-device-info"),  {
  exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
})
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"
```

Comment: I haven't used the package  `react-native-device-info` and i am getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks man. this worked for me on `"react-native": "0.59.5",`

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to your gradle.properties then clean/rebuild

```
googlePlayServicesVersion=16.1.0
firebaseVersion=17.6.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"'` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `<application>` tag

Your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ru.chopcode.myapplication">

    <application
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   </application>
```

Answer (score 4):

Downgrade Google Play service version. In `android/app/build.gradle` change

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-<service_name>:+'`

to

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-<service_name>:16.0.0'`

So in my case *< sevice_name >* was `location`. But in someone's else case it may be any other Google Play Service (like in list here http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Comment: Downgrading google play service version worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After spending a whole day on this issue. Finally, I have resolved this issue.

I got that error from react-native-device-info and react-native-fast-image library.
I just remove that library from package.json file and then install

**"react-native-device-info": "^2.1.2",
  "react-native-fast-image": "^6.0.3"**  this latest version

I have used below gradle version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

I have used below properties version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

I have used below versions

```
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 16
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [@Frank's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56646765/4153833) answer the library used `services-gcm:+` as a dependency, and the latest gcm version caused this problem.

And I had used `:react-native-admob` in my project. So I just change the following lines in `android/app/build.gradle`

From:

```
implementation project(':react-native-admob')
```

TO :

```
implementation(project(":react-native-admob"),  {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
})
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56658575/5888166) answer should help most people. If it still does not then the way to solve this (which is not that good) is that you open the android project in android studio. That should fetch all the gradle files. On the right side the view should be android.

[image]

From here just check each gradle build file for a **+** sign ahead of google play services or firebase services or any such library. This has also been explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56647134/5888166) answer.

After which you either change it like explained in the answer above. 
like so.

```
implementation(project(":react-native-admob"),  {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
})
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0"
```

Or you provide a variable if the library is using one or as a last resort change it there itself.

The reason I put it here is so that any newbie who is sick of this error which randomly appeared out of nowhere all of a sudden can solve it effectively and not...die. lol.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, just upgrade `react-native-device-info` and run the following command

```
npm upgrade react-native-device-info@latest
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading `react-native-device-info` to version 2.1.2 Fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using `react-native-device-info`, but have the same error, its probably another library in your project.

Use this to find the library in question:

```
cd your-react-native-project/android
./gradlew app:dependencies > deps.txt
```

Then inspect the deps.txt file for keyword "androidx". Then you can quickly find which native module is using it.

In my case it was `react-native-camera`, for which solution above was good but not enough so I had to add this to local.properties:

```
firebaseVersion=17.6.0
googlePlayServicesVersion=16.1.0
googlePlayServicesVisionVersion=16.2.0
```

EDIT:
After these fixes, running `./gradlew app:dependencies > deps.txt` and searching for "androidx" returned no results - this is what we are looking for.

After running **clean** on the project, build worked.

Answer (score 1):

Google play services breaking changes. See [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019).

The simple way to resolve this issue is just changing the version of Google play services.

**Change all `com.google.android.gms:play-services-*` dependencies to version 16**